# is there a way to refer to outputted object in dev console of chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Lot of times when I output an object in chrome using `console.log()`. It outputs the object and its properties in expandable tree format, which is nice. But is there a way to refer to it in console?...Like in console you can refer to Dom elements....as $0, $1, $2..etc.

Is there a way to refer to outputted objects so I can use them within in console by referring to them like: `$c.obj1.someProperty..`

This can be very useful when I am learning new Api, and debugging the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the last result using `$_` (dollar-underscore).

[image: 1 + 1 + 1 = 3 and $_ = 3]

(defined [here](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/core/inspector/InjectedScriptSource.js?revision=169376&view=markup#l1323))

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to assign it to the window object under some property.  Consider a function as follows:

```
function addDebugObject(obj) {
    var index;
    if (!window.debugObjects) {
        window.debugObjects = [];
    }
    index = window.debugObjects.length;
    window.debugObjects.push(obj);
    console.log(index, obj);
}
```

Then to use it in the console

```
> addDebugObject({'d': 4})
0 [Object]
> obj = window.debugObjects[0]
{'d': 4}
```